# IE Issue With Logo Placement

Tags: css, internet-explorer, graphical-logo

I faced my logo placement issue in IE for [Vis-a-vis](http://workspacefile.com/visavis/) website. The logo looks fine in all browser except IE. So, I tried below code to fix, but no luck. Looking forward to get a best solution.

```
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
    <style>
    div.logo img {
    margin-left:28%;
    }
    </style>
 <!--<![endif]-->

<!--[if IE]><!-->
    <style>
    div.logo img {
    margin-left:10%;
    }
    </style>
 <!--<![endif]-->
```

Thanks

Comment: What version of IE are you using? Also, please provide us with a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Hi @fizzix I am using IE 10. I need it get worked in all version. Since I couldn't fiddle the menu properly, I am giving the site link here: [link](http://workspacefile.com/visavis/)

Comment: Added my answer. Let me know how it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things are rendering incorrectly in Internet Explorer (not to sure why). So try increasing the size of your `.wrap` class and slightly increasing the left margin on the logo.

**New CSS:**

```
div.logo img {
    margin-top: -10% !important;
    margin-left: 29% !important;
    background-image: url(img/logo-bg.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    padding: 45px 59px;
    background-position: center center;
}

div.wrap {
    max-width: 916px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**EDIT:**

**[READ HERE.](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)** Using a conditional statement, like what you have does, to target IE10 and above will not work. Targeting IE9 and below is not accessible via this method. To target IE10 and above, you must use Javascript/jQuery or a specific CSS media query like below:

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {  
       div.logo img {
        margin-top: -10% !important;
        margin-left: 29% !important;
        background-image: url(img/logo-bg.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        padding: 45px 59px;
        background-position: center center;
    }

    div.wrap {
        max-width: 916px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Hi @fizzix Thanks for your reply. But the above CSS styling didn't work. I was able to fix IE10 following [CSS-TRICKS](http://css-tricks.com/ie-10-specific-styles/) but couldn't fix other ie yet. If I use below code, this is applied to all browser. 

`<!--[if !IE]><!-->
    <style>
    div.logo img {
    margin-left:28%;
    }
    </style>
 <!--<![endif]-->`